# Error : elemento div no permitido según el w3.org

Tags: html, validación, class, div

Error : elemento div no permitido como elemento secundario del elemento label en este contexto.

Este es el código:

```
<div class="slider slider-theme round">
</div> 
<div class="opt">
 <label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <div class="slider slider-theme round">
   </div>
 </label>
</div>
```

Agradecería me indiquen como solucionarlo.
Saludos cordiales
Antonio Manuel

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta con más detalles técnicos acerca de tu problema de la manera más explícita posible, esto aumentará las posibilidades de recibir una buena respuesta por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás incluyendo un div con clase slider dentro de una etiqueta label, eso no es permitido dentro de una etiqueta label. Lo que debes hacer es sacar ese div fuera del label.

```
<div class="slider slider-theme round">
</div> 
<div class="opt">
 <label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   
 </label>
 <div class="slider slider-theme round">
 </div>
</div>
```